# how i calc the time complexity in python code?

Tags: python, performance, time, time-complexity, performance-testing

Iam working on a paper so i want to calc the running time in my algorithm at many cases
so i pick python to do it the problem is when i try a several time same as input and algorithm
the result is change every time i run it

```
import time
import heapq
def dijkstra(graph, source):
    dist = {vertex: float('infinity') for vertex in graph}
    visited = set()
    dist[source] = 0
    priority_queue = [(0, source)]
    while priority_queue:
        current_distance, current_vertex = heapq.heappop(priority_queue)
        if current_vertex in visited:
            continue
        visited.add(current_vertex)
        for neighbor, edge_weight in graph[current_vertex].items():
            if neighbor in visited:
                continue
            alt = dist[current_vertex] + edge_weight
            if alt < dist[neighbor]:
                dist[neighbor] = alt
                heapq.heappush(priority_queue, (alt, neighbor))
    return dist

graph1 = {
    'A': {'B': 1},
    'B': {'A': 1}
}


start_vertex = 'A'
start_time = time.perf_counter()
distances = dijkstra(graph6, start_vertex)
end_time = time.perf_counter()
elapsed_time = (end_time - start_time) * 1e6
print(f"Elapsed time: {elapsed_time} microseconds")
```

i know maybe some of you see the solution is very clear but I am really confused
how i make sure good enough to calc the acutely time complexity

Comment: Time complexity is not calculated by *running* code, but by *analysing* it. The time you measure there is of little help to determine time complexity, as the latter is about *asymptotic* behaviour, not about a specific input.

Comment: You mean there is no way to determine the time complexity? BUT what if i run the code let's say ten times and divide it to 10 , is this help to calc it ?

Comment: You misunderstand the difference between "time-complexity" and "run time." Time complexity has nothing to do with how much time it takes for the code to run. Time complexity is about how the time it takes for the code to run changes with changes to the size of the input. Use the [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) module for run time experiments.